# code keep giving me exception. im not sure why

Tags: java

sorry if this is not allowed. it's my first time asking a question. anyways I'm supposed to implement a program that read a grade level base on the text.

"Implement a program that computes the approximate grade level needed to comprehend some text, per the below.
Text: Congratulations! Today is your day. You're off to Great Places! You're off and away! Grade 3"

after finishing the code. every time I compile it, it gives me an exception that I'm dividing by zero. almost like after I ask the user to enter the text, it's not read at all in letter count to it stays at zero. I'm not sure how to go around it.
here's my code below
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Readability {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int letterCount=0;
        int wordCount = 0;
        int sentenceCount = 0;
        
        // Just taking the input
          System.out.println("Please provide some text as input");
            String text = sc.nextLine();
        
          
            
        for (int i = 0; i< text.length(); i++) {
            // checking letters
            if ((text.charAt(i) == 'a' && text.charAt(i) == 'z') || (text.charAt(i) == 'A'  && text.charAt(i) == 'Z' ))
            {
                letterCount++;
            }
            // any chars separated by space is a word
            if (text.charAt(i) == ' ' || text.charAt(i) == '\0')
            {
                wordCount++;

            }
            // when you see a . ! or ? count as sentence
            if (text.charAt(i) == '!' || text.charAt(i) == '.'|| text.charAt(i) == '?')
            {
                sentenceCount++;
            }
            
        }
        
        
        double averageWordsPer100 = (letterCount * 100) / wordCount;
        double averageSentencePer100 = (sentenceCount * 100) / wordCount;
        int readingIndex = (int) Math.round(0.0588 * averageWordsPer100 - 0.296 * averageSentencePer100 - 15.8);
        
       

                
        if (readingIndex < 1)
        {
            System.out.println("Before Grade 1");
        }
        else if (readingIndex > 16)
        {
            System.out.println("Grade 16");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Grade " + readingIndex);
        }
       
    }
   
}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in a debugger? This is a great time to learn that skill. If you aren't able to use a debugger, you might want to add some more logging, e.g. print out the value of `text`, `letterCount`, `wordCount` and `sentenceCount`.

Comment: The code is telling you where the error is, If a single word is typed, your code doesn't register it as a word as there are no spaces.  You need to correct your method of word detection.

Comment: This condition: `if ((text.charAt(i) == 'a' && text.charAt(i) == 'z') || (text.charAt(i) == 'A'  && text.charAt(i) == 'Z' ))` is never true, so `letterCount` is always `0`. You must use `>=` and `<=`, or just replace with `if (Character.isLetter(text.charAt(i)))`. Another bug is you're not accounting for multiple non-letters between words, such as comma then space, which you count as 1 word too much.

Comment: Well, this: `text.charAt(i) == 'a' && text.charAt(i) == 'z'` cannot be true, ever.

Comment: thank you all for the help!! I was able to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

I compiled and executed the project and no problem is shown, except when  the input has 0 words. To avoid the divided by 0 exception you can add this piece of code:

```
    int readingIndex = 0;
    
    if (wordCount != 0){
        double averageWordsPer100 = (letterCount * 100) / wordCount;
        double averageSentencePer100 = (sentenceCount * 100) / wordCount;
        readingIndex = (int) Math.round(0.0588 * averageWordsPer100 - 0.296 * averageSentencePer100 - 15.8);
    }
```

You can set the initial value of readingIndex to the value you want. Then, if the wordCount is 0, the readingIndex initial value will be used.